# Magento2 : How to get the attributes values for products list page?

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, phtml, magento-2.1.9

I will trying to get the attributes values but i can't do this values ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('package_quantity');
if (empty($attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product))) {
}else{
   echo "<strong>Package Quantity : </strong>",$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product); 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attribute value and attribute code as :

**Attribute Value :**

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

**Attribute Label :**

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getStoreLabel();
```

Comment: i need only for attributes value.